# "Phase change" of a purely mathematical system

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, physics

Every so often I hear people talking about "phase transitions" in purely mathematical or computer-science contexts, where there is no physics in sight. Today, for example, I heard some people talking about "phase transitions" when coloring edges in random graphs.

Is this just a simple reuse of the [physics term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition), or is there a more general mathematical concept of a "phase change", of which physical phase changes are one instance? If so, what are some illustrative purely mathematical/nonphysical examples?

Comment: I think there is a connection via statistical mechanics, Ising models, percolation theory, etc. My naive impression is that there is a mathematical concept of phase transition (roughly speaking when the behavior of a system depends discontinuously on some continuous parameter) of which physical phase transitions are an instance.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, I think so too. I'm hoping someone knowledgeable about those fields could elaborate or give references on how to make the connection precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Where the *Really* Hard Problems Are](http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp4200/Whereproblem.pdf) the concept of phase change in NP complete problems is discussed.  It has the sense of a narrow boundary region from physics, but not entirely the sense of fixing things (like the temperature of a melting solution).

Comment: Ahh, that seems to contain a discussion of two of the examples that I've run across. It seems like more of an analogy than a direct correspondence though. There's no analogs of "entropy", "temperature", "free energy", or other quantities you would expect in thermodynamic systems. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment but ...

"Where the Really Hard Problems Are" makes a critical error relative to where the really hard problems are.

Problems in the narrow "boundary region" can be easily moved to the "over constrained region" by adding n new variables and 6n new clauses. These clauses need only involve those n varaibles, but need not. This is a polynomial transformation that has no effect on the solution to the original problem.

I would suggest that using "phase change" in this context might be improper.

Answer (score 1):

The most common example I can think of is in random graph theory, which serves as the mathematical model of all sorts of networks, where an abrupt transition occurs between the *disconnected* regime and the *connected* regime when the probability of the existence of an edge between two nodes exceeds $\log n/n$, where $n$ is the number of nodes (vertices). If calling that a "phase change" is an abuse, then so be it.